# Angular Material Table with Selection Model and server side pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination

I have an `Angular Material table` with `pagination` and a `selection model` to get some rows to do stuff.
Currently I'm changing the `pagination` with `server-side pagination`, but with this my selection model brokes. While i'm changing the page, I can add rows to the selection model, and works fine. But when I going back to a previous page, the rows (which are in the selection model) doesn't appear checked.

My selection model, with the methods are just equal to the ones published in the demo page of angular material:

```js
  selection = new SelectionModel<ItemManagementViewDTO>(true, []);

  isAllSelected(): boolean {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected?.length;
    const numRows = this.items?.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }
 

  masterToggle(): void {
    this.isAllSelected() ? this.selection.clear() : this.items?.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  checkboxLabel(row?: ItemManagementViewDTO): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.idItem + 1}`;
  }
```

The html is simple:

```html
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="items" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
        <!-- Checkbox Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox
              (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
              [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
              [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
              [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"
              color="primary"
            >
            </mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)" color="primary">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
<!-- ... -->
<mat-paginator [length]="totalItems" (page)="onPageChange($event)" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

My `OnPageChange` with `server-side` pagination is:

```js
  onPageChange(event: PageEvent): void {
    this.itemsServ.getPaginatedItems(this.paramsStored, event.pageIndex, event.pageSize).subscribe(r => {
      this.items = r.listDTO;
      this.totalItems = r.totalElements;
  }
```

What I am missing? Every time I change page, the source is refreshed, but the item still exists in the selection model (if I added it). Why it don't appear checked if it's the same item as in the previous call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SelectionModel](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts) uses internally a **Set** to store all selected elements.

**SelectionModel.isSelected** method uses the **Set.has** method which returns a boolean indicating whether an element exisists in a **Set**.

Here is an example what happens if you use **Set.has** with a different object reference.

```
var set1 = new Set();
var obj1 = {'key1': 1};
set1.add(obj1);

set1.has(obj1);        // returns true
set1.has({'key1': 1}); // returns false because they are different object references
```

In your case if you switch back and forth the table has the same data but different references.

One solution is to replace/remove the selected items with the new ones.

```
onPageChange(event: PageEvent): void {
     this.itemsServ.getPaginatedItems(this.paramsStored, event.pageIndex, event.pageSize).subscribe(r => {
     this.items = r.listDTO;
     // replace old selected items with new ones
     const itemsToAdd= items.
           filter(item=> {
              const foundItem = this.selection.selected.find(selectedItem=> selectedItem.id === item.id);
              if(!foundItem) return;
              // removes item from selection
              this.selection.deselect(foundItem);
              return item;
           });
      
     this.selection.select(itemsToAdd);
     this.totalItems = r.totalElements;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. I haven't checked to see if the accepted answer works, but here is a cleaner alternative.

First, write a new method to determine whether a row is checked. This will be used to override the SelectionModel's comparison method:

```
isChecked(row: any): boolean {
    const found = this.selection.selected.find(el => el._id === row._id);
    if (found) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Then in your ngOnInit, tell the SelectionModel to use your new method for comparison.

```
this.selection.isSelected = this.isChecked.bind(this);
```

With this method, you don't need to replace objects in the selection set at all.

(source: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9670#issuecomment-455117080)

Comment: You can provide `compareWith` fn as custom comparator. https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/api#SelectionModel