# How to remain mat-checkbox checked after a page change in Angular?

Tags: angular

Here is my mat-checkbox.

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
   (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null"
   [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by following the recommendation on these links.

[Angular Material Table with Selection Model and server side pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739315/angular-material-table-with-selection-model-and-server-side-pagination)

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9670#issuecomment-455117080

Comment: Please do not just put links on your answer, as links may not be broken over the time. Post the recommendations directly

Answer (score 0):

My solution was that I used a boolean variable to hold a checkbox's value.

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="toggleCheckBox($event.checked)"
 [checked]="sendMailToManagerAlso" 
color="primary"
 *ngIf="selection.selected.length > 0">Apply managers
</mat-checkbox>
```

TS

```
export class MyTsClass{
    
public sendMailToManagerAlso: boolean = false;

constructor(){ }

 toggleCheckBox(check: boolean){
     this.sendMailToManagerAlso = check;
 }

}
```